# How do I reduce the sugar in this recipe without affecting the taste?

Tags: sauce, sugar

How do I make my [Italian sweet sauce](http://www.food.com/recipe/italian-sweet-sauce-296587) be lower in sugar without affecting the taste? Last time I made it I was 5, as a result there is a lot of bugs that I need corrected, but I'm starting with the sugar problem first. I don't have much of a sense of taste/smell.(I don't want to eat too much sugar.)

Comment: I personally think that there should be a food - preperation tab. The fact is the only reason I put down food - science tab, it's the closest to the tab I was going for.

Comment: *Please* provide recipes when you're asking how to modify a recipe. You can just paste the url into the question, or use the link button to add a nice link.

Comment: And for tags: the reason there's no general food-preparation tag is that it would apply to basically every question here. The point of tags is to note information that's relatively specific to the question at hand, to make it easier to find certain types of questions. See [this blog post on meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for more.

Comment: The recipe supplied looks a little suspicious to me. What are the ingredients of the "Italian Dressing"? How much sugar is in that? They also use artificial eggs (dietary requirement?). French mustard and Chinese spice. How Italian is this going to be? 4Tbsp sugar is not that much in 7 cups yield. Also only has 1 not so good review.

Comment: the original recipe if I remember correctly used real eggs, I chose artificial eggs is because I thought those were healthear that's all @mintyfreshpenguin. Youmight want to know that the recipe name comes from the itailian dressing, NOT because it's itailan.

Comment: @AbrahamRay My sincere apologies, I meant no offence. I just noticed that you wrote the recipe.  I see - you are not using the word "Italian" as an objective to describe something from Italy.

Comment: @Jefromi Sorry to add an off-topic comment, but I just wanted to thank you for that blog-post link. It clears up things I've been wondering about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an artificial sweetener. There's no single best one, just pick whatever suits your tastes. The packaging will hopefully have conversion factors (or you can look them up online). They probably won't be perfect, but they'll give you a starting point for how much to use to replace the sugar in the recipe.

Answer (score 5):

Since the bulk of this recipe is "Italian dressing", I would start there, before considering alternative sweeteners.  Bottled Italian dressing probably is sweetened to begin with (check ingredients...look for corn syrup, sucrose...etc.).  You could begin the process by making your own dressing, without sweeteners, if this is the case.  Alternately, you could systematically reduce the added 4TBS sugar, until you get to a sweetness that you like...or maybe you don't even need that extra sugar, and leave it out altogether.  Another option making things taste less sweet is to replace table sugar with isomalt, as it is less sweet tasting.

Comment: remember I want to reduce the sugar WITHOUT reducing the sweet taste.

Comment: Does Honey works well in Italian Dressing? Since I don't know much about Italian Cuisine but may be we can use that right?

Comment: I believe so @thedictator